# Why don't we overheat just by existing? What is the theoretical model?

Tags: biophysics, thermal-conductivity

Our bodies constantly generate heat, but we don't overheat just by sitting in room temperature! Why?

Something about the shape of our bodies at standard-temperature-pressure is at equilibrium with the rate that the surrounding air accepts excess radiated heat.

The average surface area of a human body is 1.75m^2 (averaging between men and women). The heat transfer coefficient, if I understand correctly according to this article https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288212774_Determining_heat_transfer_coefficient_of_human_body is about 3.6.

Can we modify and work with Newton's law of cooling to model why we don't overheat just by existing?

Comment: I don't know about you, but when I get (too?) hot, I tend to [perspire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspiration).

Comment: But do you "get too hot" and "perspire" sitting at room temperature, without exercising? Because I didn't ask about when you get too hot, I asked about when you don't. Why we don't overheat sitting at room temperature I think this is a perfectly valid question that takes expertise in physical modeling to address, if not crude approximations of a simple differential equation.

Comment: Considering sweating is literally the biomechanical response to increased core temperature, yes you can absolutely sweat at room temperature without exercising.

Comment: I have years of evidence to the contrary. I'm sitting right now at above room temperature and am not sweating. I think you are mistaken in the problem parameters.

Comment: I don't think I am. If your core internal temperature increases, you sweat. There's a few millennia of evidence showing that, even if your body is weird enough to not.

Comment: Yes, perspiration is basically something that's happing all the time,  If it's not trickling down your body, that means that it's doing its job sufficiently efficiently that it's evaporating before the droplets get large enough for you to consciously notice.

Comment: Consider the classic 100W bulb - about what your body puts out at rest. The glass does get hot. Now spread that heat over the ~2 square meters and how hot would it feel?

Comment: Let's assume what you're saying is correct, you're STILL not "too hot" at room temperature because your body is maintaining its internal temperature through this perspiration process, and the effect of cooling is still proportional to surface area. So your point is still moot. The water on your skin from sweating needs to transfer its excess energy somewhere else to cool your body, that somewhere is air.

Comment: In outer space you would freeze in an instant. We don't overheat because we cool off.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to send a comment but I don't have enough reputation points. The reason you don't overheat is because your body is at 98° while your surroundings (room temperature) are at 68° Heat flows from hot to cold so all the calories you burn that are not used for work are used to heat up your environment. Since air is a poor conductor of heat, we can overheat on days when the air temperature is close to body temperature or higher. Our body compensates through perspiration because water conducts heat much better than air. If air conducted heat as well as water, we woukd all die of hypothermia within minutes on a 32° day. Sorry I couldn't send this as a comment.

Comment: I agree, heat flows outside your body. But, here I'm looking for a mathematical model that demonstrates this. The rate your body generates heat, which according to one poster is equivalent to a 100W bulb, is in some way at equilibrium with the rate it loses heat to the surroundings. How do we show *mathematically* how this happens?

Comment: I came across this in another thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277074/how-to-find-the-power-required-to-maintain-object-temperature-in-a-different-tem. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @StackQuest just calculate all the usual heat transfer mechanisms: conduction, convection and radiation.

Answer (score 1):

[I reiterate my advice to look through an introductory heat transfer text to become familiar with standard modeling approaches.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/707040/how-do-i-approximate-temperature-changes-of-an-applied-cooled-paint)

**Conduction**: Say you're resting on a (very thermally conductive) material—stone or metal—about 10°C colder then your body temperature (at your blood vessels, about a centimeter deep), with a contact area of about a meter squared. The thermal conductivity of skin $k$ is similar to that of water, about 1 W/m-K. The heat transfer (in units of power) is, from Fourier's law,

$$Q=kA\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}=1000\,\text{W}.$$

**Convection**: Say you're in a cool breeze, 10°C cooler than your skin (effective area of a meter squared), with an effective convection coefficient $h$ of 10 W/m²-K. The heat transfer is, from a convection model,

$$Q=hA(T-T_\infty)=100\,\text{W}.$$

**Radiation**: Say you're facing the night sky, effective atmosphere temperature about a hundred degrees cooler than your skin (about 300 K, emissivity $\epsilon$ about 1). The heat transfer is, from the Stefan–Boltzmann Law,

$$Q=\sigma\epsilon A(T^4-T_\infty^4)\approx 370\,\text{W}.$$

**Latent heat**: Say you're sweating moderately at a rate of about 100 grams per hour. For a latent heat $L$ around room temperature of about 2 kJ/g, the heat transfer is $$Q=\dot{m}L\approx 60\,\text{W}.$$

On a cool dry night, we have no problems dissipating our 100 W of metabolic heat! Indeed, the struggle may be to stay warm. But change at least two of these three qualifiers, and we begin to have a problem.